# Sample versus subject in scRNA-seq

Tags: scrnaseq

I am reading [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41592-019-0576-7) paper, where the authors mention

> We apply SAUCIE to the batch correcting, denoising and clustering of
> an 11-million cell mass cytometry dataset with 180 samples from 40
> subjects in a study of the dengue flavivirus

What exactly is the difference between a “sample” and a “subject” in scRNA-Seq?

PS: here’s a possibly relevant visual from the paper, but I still couldn’t understand the difference
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subject is an individual or donor. You can take multiple samples from the same subject, e.g. from different tissues, different timepoints etc.